# In QT, radio button and checkmark graphics distorted in HIGH DPI

Tags: qt, highdpi

Check Windowsflag sample application provided by QT

Enable high DPI scaling flag  with

SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(permonitor V2);

QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

Problem:

When Dialog is moved across different DPI monitors, radio button and check mark graphics break on low DPI monitor(100%, 1920x1080). Sample application is lunched on HDPI monitor(4K 300%). Check attached Image

[image: Monitor 2 (100% scaling) 1980x1080]
Monitor 2 (100% scaling) 1980x1080

[image]

Comment: Your two images look identical. I'm not sure what we should be seeing.

Comment: sorry for images, I have updated all images

Comment: open both images and compare radio button and check mark graphics